# How to identify which network interface is used for a given route?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip, windows-networking

I am on a Windows 10 machine. I have got the below routes configured in my machine.

```
Network Destination      Netmask            Gateway       Interface      Metric
0.0.0.0                  0.0.0.0            192.168.1.1   192.168.1.5    1
10.1.0.0                 255.255.0.0        192.168.2.1   192.168.2.5    1
10.2.0.0                 255.255.0.0        192.168.3.1   192.168.3.5    1
```

When ping IP **10.1.1.1**, I want to determine which network interface will be used to route the traffic.

Is there any network utility that can help me find the correct route based on the destination IP?

Comment: The most specific route (Network Destination with most bits matching the destination address) wins, and in the case of a tie, the lowest Metric wins.

Answer (score 0):

If you ping `10.1.1.1`, it will use the interface with the IP `192.168.2.5` looking at your route table.

You can also use `tracert 10.1.1.1` to see what route your network traffic will take.